# Terminal velocity Vs Relaxation time

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, brownian-motion

I'm surely trapped in a misunderstanding.

Consider an experimental situation where a molecule is dropped into water, and imagine that the viscous force $\eta v$ perfectly compensates the gravitational force. Soon the molecule will attain a *terminal drift velocity*.

However, the *Brownian relaxation time* is defined as the characteristic time over which the particle motion becomes causal.

But in what sense the motion becomes causal, if the molecule keeps falling at a constant velocity?

Comment: There are stochastic forces due to the movement of the water molecules, which cause the random Brownian motion. Even objects as large as pollen show significant Brownian motion and do not reach a terminal drift velocity. For large objects the Brownian motion becomes negligibly small and they do indeed reach a constant drift velocity.

Comment: @SebastianRiese, your comment is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two concepts have different ranges of validity:

- Viscous force and terminal drift velocity make sense in scales large enough so that the (continuous) fluid description applies.
- Brownian motion is exhibited at scales that are small enough for the molecules' thermal, chaotic movement to have noticeable effect.

By definition these scales do not overlap, thus there's no conflict. The molecule that enters the water volume is going to see it as a multitude of particles which constantly hit it and will therefore simply display Brownian motion.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I've understood correctly, some bodies (i.e. those "small enough") don't necessarily keep falling, instead remain in suspension (as @Sebastian Riese wrote in his valuable comment), where the "brownian bombardment" keeps going on

Comment: @LoScrondo Yes, it won't be able to simply fall, because the collisions with the water molecules will be much stronger than its weight.